# foreach in a group with a where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have something like this:

```
    var groups = items.GroupBy(item => item.ListId);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
     Console.WriteLine("List with ID == {0}", group.Key);
     foreach(var item in group)
        Console.WriteLine("    Item: {0}", item.ItemName);
}
```

how do I do a where clause in the second foreach statement, like foreach(var item in group where id == 2) for different Ids, like where Id == 2, where Id == 3, and so on. and I dont want to use if statement. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an if statement?  What would you expect to use instead?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Without a good [mcve] that shows what you tried, and a detailed explanation of why that didn't work (including why you would think you _would_ use an `if` statement in any solution), you might require any number of different solutions. That said, the marked duplicate shows one approach. Consider as an alternative the `Contains()` method of a `HashSet()` object set up specifically to contain the ids you want to filter on.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it before you group the items if you want, like this:

```
var excludeItems = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
var groups = items
    .Where(item => !excludeItems.Contains(item.ListId))
    .GroupBy(item => item.ListId);
```

Or you can do it in the `foreach` like this assuming it has `Id` memeber:

```
// 1 or some other Id or you can use the `Contains` approach
// here as well as I showed above
foreach(var item in group.Where(x => x.Id == 1))  
{
    //... 
}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile, never mind is it going to handle arbitrary sets of id values.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well I figured the OP will put the values in. Anyhow, yes it wouldn't have compiled that way. But the idea was there.